The more there of us....?
Is this a natural sounding phase in this context?
The more there are of us, the sooner we'll finish.

The phrase the more there are of us has many pages of hits in usages  in Google Books similar to the OP's suggestion.
The OP’s suggested use is natural.

Thank you very much
